# Unity iOS Ways to, or if it is possible, to disable the input on the spacebar

Tags: ios, input, keyboard, unity-game-engine

Been trying to come up with some ways to disable the spacebar input when using the iOS keyboard. I need to check a string entered from the keyboard against a result string, and as it stand when spacebars are entered it returns incorrect, as they are obviously part of the string.

I have tried the following:

```
if (keyboard.text.Length < 12 && !Event.current.Equals(Event.KeyboardEvent("space")))
{                   
    answerTextMesh.text = keyboard.text.ToLower();
    answerTextMesh.Commit();
}
```

Is there a way to disable the input on the iOS keyboard spacebar, or should I just try and strip out spaces from the string as they are entered?

Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you are using JavaScript.

I've found this snippet, maybe it'll help you! I haven't tested this myself yet:

```
private var text = "Pressing Space won't work!";

function DisableKey( key : KeyCode )
{
    if( Event.current.keyCode == key && ( Event.current.type == EventType.KeyUp || Event.current.type == EventType.KeyDown ) )
    {
         Event.current.Use();
    }
}

function OnGUI()
{
     DisableKey( KeyCode.Space );
     text = GUILayout.TextArea( text );
}
```